# react-router.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```html
 
 <!-- Included Script --> 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
  
    
 <div id="root"></div>
 
    <script type="text/babel"> 
  
  var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
        var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
        var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
        var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
        var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

        class Page extends React.Component {
          
            render() {
                return (
                     <div>
                         <Link to='/about'>India </Link>
                     </div>
                );
            }
        }

        class About extends React.Component {
          
            render() {
                return (
                        <div>
                            to Router
                        </div>
                );
            }
        }

        class NoMatch extends React.Component {
          
            render() {
                return (
                        <div>
                           No page found
                        </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={Page}>
                    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );

    </script>
```

It always give me 'location' of undefined error. Have tried slimier answers in other posts but it still not working for me.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## React-router-dom

Use `react-router-dom` ( DOM bindings for React Router)

## Install

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

## Use

Just use `ReactRouterDOM` instead of `ReactRouter`:

```
var Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
var Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
```

> You can find the library on window.ReactRouterDOM.

[github/react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom)

## Basic Example

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

Comment: Hi btzr , i want to follow umd as i need to run this project without Node js

Comment: Hey its working now error is gone . Thanks for your help . now have one small issue . this is my main url http://localhost/my-app1/ and when i click on route for about it removes my-app1 and loads http://localhost/about.

Comment: You should create a new question. But first take the time to debug this issue.

Comment: Yes Thanks for your help . you save my day

Comment: And also check the new syntax in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to put history="browserHistory" in Router tag under ReactDom.
    
    `<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route/>
    </Router>`

Comment: Hi Rinku have added this in code but still not working . have added whole code in snippet so you can test it.

Comment: Ok, first check out which version of react-router u r using, bcoz there are a lot changes in router v3 and v4. In v4 u cannot export browserhistory from react-router.

Comment: Definitely not setup properly for v4 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You said you are using v4 in a comment... so a couple things immediately stand out and *yes* that type of information is super important to getting a correct answer.

Your `<App/>` needs to be wrapped around the router object as noted in the documentation.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

```
<Router>
    <App/>
</Router>
```

If you are using v4, you do *not* need to pass in history... like, `<Router history={...}`, this is handled for you. You simply need to have installed the history package... so in your case find a CDN for it.

You multiple routes should be placed within a `<Switch/>`.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

```
<Switch>
    <Route/>
    <Route/>
    ...
</Switch>
```

This is how v4 more or less determines which route to select, similar to running a switch statement as it may be.

Start with that or consider a v3 cdn.

You should take the time to read this documentation thoroughly. The React Router team has phenomenal documentation that is easy to follow and implement into toy projects as well as production ready Redux or Relay applications.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy